How about use Next.js Route Handler as backends to create both web and apps?
I want to create both mobile app and website like Threads. I'm going to create a mobile app using React Native + Expo with Next.js and use Next.js for the website. How about using Next.js Route Handler as a backend for both the web and the app?
First of all, I only know about Next.js (TypeScript), and I have never learned anything else.
In conclusion, the methods I thought of are as follows.

App(RN + Expo with Next.js), Web, Backend(Next.js)
App(RN + Expo with Next.js), Web(Next.js), Backend(Nest.js)

DB needs to learn, but it's not urgent, so it's okay to take a little longer. If both of the above methods are not good, please recommend another good method!
